# Drag an item out of recyclerview to another view

Tags: java, android

I created a recycler view where the items can be dragged. The following is from my adapter:

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(final FootballPitchMainAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.rvPlayerNameTop.setText("testing");
        holder.linearLayoutFull.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                    View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(
                            view);
                    view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
                    view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
```

Now this does work, I can drag the linearLayout, which contains an imageView and a texview. The drag allows me to move the items out of the recyclerview.

If I used motion, I couldn't move the linearlayout frame out of the RV.

But my problem is, once I drag the view, I want to be able to place it anywhere on the screen.

So in the class where the RV is created, I set the following:

```
pitchRelativeLayout.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
     class MyDragListener implements View.OnDragListener{

            @Override
            public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
                switch(event.getAction()) {
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                        //Do nothing
                        break;

                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                        break;

                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED :
                        break;

                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION  :
                        break;

                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED   :
                        // Do nothing
                        break;

                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                        View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                        ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                        owner.removeView(view);
                        RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) v;
                        container.addView(view);
                        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                    default: break;
                }
                return true;

            }
        }
```

PitchLayout is a relativelayout which covers the entire screen. The idea is just to drag an item from RV and drop it anywhere.

Here is an image which I hope explains this better:
[image: PitchLayout]

I am trying to tell the relative layout to listen to the drag item and on the drop, place it here.
The above code is from online tutorials I have tried, answers from Stackover Flow